# How to setup `vite-plugin-pages`, cannot find module `~pages`

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3, vite

I'm trying to set up file system based routing for a Vue 3 application using Vite with the help of [`vite-plugin-pages`](https://github.com/hannoeru/vite-plugin-pages).

I created the project using `yarn create vite` with `vue-ts` as the options and added the plugin via `yarn add vite-plugin-pages --dev`, `yarn add vue-router`.

Following the readme on the github, I have added the following to my `vite.config.ts`:

```
import Pages from 'vite-plugin-pages'

export default {
  plugins: [
    // ...
    Pages(),
  ],
}
```

However, at the next step, in `main.ts`:

```
import { createRouter } from 'vue-router'
import routes from '~pages'

const router = createRouter({
  // ...
  routes,
})
```

I cannot seem to import from `~pages`. I cannot find the module. `vue-router` itself is working fine, as I can create a router fine, declaring the `routes` myself. In a [vite template](https://github.com/antfu/vitesse/blob/main/src/main.ts), they seem to be using `import routes from 'virtual:generated-pages'` instead and I have no idea how either works.

So, the question is, **how would I go about generating the dynamic routes and as a whole, set up the usage of `vite-plugin-pages`**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this:

```js
import Pages from "vite-plugin-pages" 

export default defineConfig({ 
    plugins: [ 
        Pages({
            pagesDir: [
                {dir: 'src/pages', baseRoute: ''},
            ],
            extensions: ['vue'],
            syncIndex: true,
            replaceSquareBrackets: true,
            extendRoute(route) {
                if (route.name === 'about')
                    route.props = route => ({query: route.query.q})

                if (route.name === 'components') {
                    return {
                        ...route,
                        beforeEnter: (route) => {
                            // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
                            // console.log(route)
                        },
                    }
                }
            },
        }), 
    ],
});
```

Then in `main.js`

```js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router';
import generatedRoutes from 'virtual:generated-pages'; 

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes: generatedRoutes,
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked, though VSCode still gives me an error for importing from 'virtual:generated-pages'. I checked it works by passing `generatedRoutes`, then adding a new page at `pages/someRoute/index.vue`. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Also, `replaceSquareBrackets: true` gives me a Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'never' error.

Comment: Huh, I was trying to localize the problem as a lot of the options you suggested seemed to be the same as the default and even if I just use `Pages({})`, it seems to work despite the IDE Error, with bth `virtual:generated-pages` and `~pages`. What exactly is this `virtual:` and `~` syntax on `import`? I would be grateful if you could guide me to a resource.

Comment: Well, the tilda sign is commonly used as an alias to the `node_modules` folder - but it depends on your `vite.config.js`. For example, in mine it looks like `resolve: {
    preserveSymlinks: true,
    alias: {
      '@': resolve(__dirname, './src'),
      src: resolve(__dirname, './src'),
      '~': resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/'),
    },
  },` The `virtual:generated-pages` is a "virtual" file (it does not exist on disk - only in RAM) generated by the Pages plugin so you can grab the auto-generated routes from there. I have no clue about the type errors as I'm not using TypeScript.

Comment: Ohh, that makes a lot of sense. Mine just says `defineConfig({plugins: [vue(), Pages()]})`, so I guess some of those are default values. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Turns out the type error was because I didn't import the types correctly.

Answer (score 2):

```
// tsconfig.json
"compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "types":  ["vite-plugin-pages/client"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also declare the reference in any of your type declarations.

```
/// <reference types="vite-plugin-pages/client" />
```